# State machine with callback functions

Tags: c++, design-patterns, state

I have a class contain multiple callbacks and a state variable s.

```
class foo
{
    public:
    void callback_1();
    void callback_2();
    ...
    private:
    State m_s;
}
```

Each callback function is connected to an external event through something similar to the boost or Qt's signal-slot.

Whether a callback shall be executed depends on the current state *m_s*,
and each callback function has the right to modify the *m_s* according to a state machine.

What is the best coding practice/pattern that can be adopted to write clean, modular code for this kind of state machine?

Comment: With a little initialization you could use a [map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) from `State` to a [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Like use a function pointer? Could you kindly show me a short example, I know how to do it if all callbacks are triggered with the same signal, but not so clear if they are triggered with different signals.

Comment: Not function pointers, but rather use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead. And once you have your map initialized, the state-machine is nothing more than a loop calling functions from that map, like `while (continue_state_machine) { my_state_map[m_s](); }`.

Comment: I find it difficult to get "[e]ach callback function is connected to an external event" to agree with "[w]hether a callback shall be executed depends on the current state". The decision can't be made in two places.

Comment: You may want to read about deterministic finate automatons, either as Mealy or Moore variant. And maybe you want to read about the state pattern described by the GoF